# Username availability checking using Ajax in JSP and stopping form submission

Tags: ajax, validation, jsp

I am new to ajax and I am trying to create a gmail type username availability check by using Ajax and JavaScript in JSP.

My code works well for username availability check but I am not able to stop the form submission when a username is not available.

For checking username availability I used onkeyup() which checks each character, but for preventing the form submission I used onsubmit() in form tag.

For execution flow check I used alert statements in this code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function returnFunction(str)
{
    alert("1");
    var flag = new Boolean(false);
    usernameValidation(str);
    alert("2");
    function usernameValidation(str)
    {
        alert("3");
        var xmlHttpRequest;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            alert("4");
            xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            alert("5");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("6");
            xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            alert("7");
            if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4 && xmlHttpRequest.status==200)
            {
                alert("8");
                if(xmlHttpRequest.responseText=="available")
                {
                    flag=new Boolean(true);
                    alert("9 flag:"+flag);
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="username is available";
                }
                else
                {
                    flag=new Boolean(false);
                    alert("10 flag:"+flag);
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="username is already taken";
                }
            }
        };
        xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "UsernameCheck", true);
        xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
        xmlHttpRequest.send("uname="+str);
    };
    alert("before return flag is:"+flag);
    return flag;
};
    function formValidation(){
        if(returnFunction(document.f1.username.value))
            {
              alert("caught flage:true");
              return true;
            }
        else{
            alert("caught flage:false");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="register"  name="f1" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
    User Name:<div id="myDiv1"><input type="text" name="username" size="20" onkeyup="returnFunction(this.value)"></div>
            <span id="myDiv" style="color: red"></span>

            <input type="submit" value="register">
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your ajax working fine.????

Comment: yes..it is. it is working for the username validation but...it is not stopping when submitting the form even when the username not available.

Comment: solved this problem by using another function and another span....

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous  so your call to returnFunction , need not return the correct flag, it will return false always as most probably success function will be triggered only after method is completed(onresponse).
So you need to ensure that response of Ajax cal is recieved using a `completed` boolean, and continuously checking it until it is true.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function returnFunction(str)
{
alert("1");
var flag = new Boolean(false);
var completed = new Boolean(false);
usernameValidation(str);
alert("2");
function usernameValidation(str)
{
    alert("3");
    var xmlHttpRequest;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        alert("4");
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("5");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("6");
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert("7");
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4 && xmlHttpRequest.status==200)
        {
            alert("8");
            if(xmlHttpRequest.responseText=="available")
            {
                flag=new Boolean(true);
                alert("9 flag:"+flag);
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="username is available";
            }
            else
            {
                flag=new Boolean(false);
                alert("10 flag:"+flag);
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="username is already taken";
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "UsernameCheck", true);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
    xmlHttpRequest.send("uname="+str);
};
alert("before return flag is:"+flag);
return flag;
};
function formValidation(){
   returnFunction(username);
   while(!completed) {
   //wait for ajax response
   }
   if(flag)
        {
          alert("caught flage:true");
          return true;
        }
    else{
        alert("caught flage:false");
        return false;
    }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: hi subin...thanx for ur reply. but i couldn't understand the logic.i tried using while(xmlHttpRequest.responseText!=null){return flag;} but the loop becoming infinite loop. and i tried with if(xmlHttpRequest.responseText!=null) {return flag;} even its null it returning flag.instead of not returning....can u explain clearly.plz thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var flag = new Boolean(false);
function returnFunction(str)
{
alert("1");

usernameValidation(str);
alert("2");
function usernameValidation(str)
{
    alert("3");
    var xmlHttpRequest;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        alert("4");
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("5");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("6");
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert("7");
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4 && xmlHttpRequest.status==200)
        {
            alert("8");
            if(xmlHttpRequest.responseText=="available")
            {
                flag=new Boolean(true);
                alert("9 flag:"+flag);
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="username is available";
            }
            else
            {
                flag=new Boolean(false);
                alert("10 flag:"+flag);
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="username is already taken";
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "UsernameCheck", true);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
    xmlHttpRequest.send("uname="+str);
};
alert("before return flag is:"+flag);
return flag;
};
function formValidation(){
    if(returnFunction(document.f1.username.value))
        {
          alert("caught flage:true");
          document.f1.submit();

        }
    else{
        alert("caught flage:false");
        alert("Username chossen by u is already taken.Please choose different Username");
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="register"  name="f1" >
User Name:<div id="myDiv1"><input type="text" name="username" size="20"         onkeyup="returnFunction(this.value)"></div>
        <span id="myDiv" style="color: red"></span>

        <input type="submit" value="register">
        </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

make changes like this it will work .if any prob let be know.

Comment: thanx for u reply...how can it work??? the function always returning flag as false. then even we modified in formValidation() as document.f1.submit(); it was not handy here ...so plz try in some other way..

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function getXMLHttpRequest(){
      var xmlHttpReq = false;
      // to create XMLHttpRequest object in non-Microsoft browsers
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } 
      else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
          // to create XMLHttpRequest object in later versions
          // of Internet Explorer
          xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (exp1) {
          try {
            // to create XMLHttpRequest object in older versions
            // of Internet Explorer
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (exp2) {
            xmlHttpReq = false;
          }
        }
      }
      return xmlHttpReq;
    };
    function usernameValidation(str)
    {
        if (str.length==0) 
        { 
            document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML="should not be empty";
            return false;
        }
        else if(str.length<=4)
        {
                document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML="need more than 4 charachers";
                return false;
        }
        else{
                var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange =function()
                {
                    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState < 4 && xmlHttpRequest.readyState > 0)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML = "<img src='images/load.gif' alt='checking...' width=16 height=16/>";
                    }
                    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                        if(xmlHttpRequest.responseText=="available")
                        {
                            document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML = "<img src='images/ok.png' alt='username available' width=16 height=16/>";
                            document.getElementById("uname1").innerHTML = ".";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            document.getElementById("uname").innerHTML = "username not available";
                        }
                    }
                };
                xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "UsernameCheck", true);
                xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHttpRequest.send("uname="+str);

            };
    };

function userSubmitValidation(){
    var msg = document.getElementById("uname1").innerHTML;  
    if(msg=='.'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="register"  name="f1"  onsubmit="return userSubmitValidation()">
    User Name:<div id="myDiv1"><input type="text" name="username" size="20" onkeyup="usernameValidation(this.value)" onblur="usernameValidation(this.value)"></div>
            <span id="uname" style="color: red"></span><span id="uname1" style="color: white"></span>

            <input type="submit" value="register">
            </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am new at ajax too and i am kind of trying to do the same thing as you are doing. I have successfully checked the username availability using ajax and jsp. Then the thing i stuck at that even if a username is not available the page still submit after clicking submit button. Then I used javascript to solve this problem. I compared the returned text with another text declared before. If check successful then it will go to next page otherwise not. For details please check this page->"[Ajax based username availablity checking and then generating some username to use in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158312/ajax-based-username-availablity-checking-and-then-generating-some-username-to-us)". There check out the sample.jsp code. In that code a i did the checking part in the function named "conditions()". In that function the variable "checkvalue" hold the returned text which is generated by  availability check. Then i compare it with the text "available". If matches then the page will submit other wise not. I am not sure is this what you wanted to know or not and if it is then my answer helps you or not. Thank you and good luck..