# how do i create a clickable link which link to a text box in same page in html

Tags: html

i want a html a format in such a way that i can select a body text by clicking on it and it will appear in a text box in the same page in html.. for example lets say that a text "example" in body section. if i click on it, it which is the text "example" will appear in a text box on the same page. Thanx in advance...

```
<html>
<body>
    name <input type=text name=name>
    example[<- I WANT THIS TEXT TO BE APPEAR ON THE NAME TEXT BOX IF I CLICK ON IT]
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code. I was not clear about the selection procedure you said above but I have two solution after you have selected the text. Hope it helps. I have used jQuery.

**Solution 1:**
I have provided a link to show the selection in a text box.

**Html:**

```
<div> 
<p>THIS TEXT TO BE APPEAR ON THE NAME TEXT BOX IF I CLICK ON IT</p><br/>
<a href="#" id='click'> click</a><br/>
<input type='text' id='box1' value="Select Text" /> 
</div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
if(!window.Kolich){
  Kolich = {};
}

Kolich.Selector = {};
Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}

Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
  var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
  if(st!=''){
    $('#box1').val(st);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#click').click(Kolich.Selector.mouseup);
});
```

**Solution 2:**

**HTML:**

```
 <div> 
 <p>Thisdt I want to extract</p>
 <input type='text' id='box1' value="Select Text" /> 
 </div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
if(!window.Kolich){
  Kolich = {};
}

Kolich.Selector = {};
Kolich.Selector.getSelected = function(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
  }else if(document.selection){
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return t;
}

Kolich.Selector.mouseup = function(){
  var st = Kolich.Selector.getSelected();
  if(st!=''){
    $('#box1').val(st);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("mouseup", Kolich.Selector.mouseup);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you.But sorry for my less knowledge,i don't know anything about jquery.I should have made myself clearer to you.Actually right now i am working with jsp and ajax,and what i am doing, username availability checking using ajax(done successfully)and then returning some generated username(if not availability)which will be in such a format that if user clicks on it,it will appear in the username text box(like we see in gmail registration form).I am very sorry again.i should have said it earlier.And thank you again for your help.Could you please help me again..thanx..

Comment: I am refering to the code i have written in another question tag. here is the link->  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158312/ajax-based-username-availablity-checking-and-then-generating-some-username-to-us] Here i didn't write the returning generated username algorith...but let's just say i did it...So now how can i do it??? Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Upon double click on any word, it gets displayed in the text box.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").dblclick(function () {
                $("#test").val(getSelectionText());
            });
        });

        function getSelectionText() {
            var text = "";
            if (window.getSelection) {
                text = window.getSelection().toString();
            } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
                text = document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
            return text;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test" type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <div>
        Lucky day</div>
    <p>
        Hello world!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you.But sorry for my less knowledge,i don't know anything about jquery.I should have made myself clearer to you.Actually right now i am working with jsp and ajax,and what i am doing, username availability checking using ajax(done successfully)and then returning some generated username(if not availability)which will be in such a format that if user clicks on it,it will appear in the username text box(like we see in gmail registration form).I am very sorry again.i should have said it earlier.And thank you again for your help.Could you please help me again..thanx..

Comment: I am refering to the code i have written in another question tag. here is the link-> [stackoverflow.com/questions/14158312/… Here i didn't write the returning generated username algorith...but let's just say i did it...So now how can i do it??? Thanx in advance...